# Should python-eve oplog record deleted document body?

Tags: eve

There is no way currently to find out the contents of the item that was deleted. Versions history is erased on delete and even the oplog with audit only records the id of doc that was deleted but not the contents.
Is there a particular reason for this?

My usecase is that I want to give a way to review changes and possibly revert them. Oplog seems like the right tool for this, except for deletes.

Is the expectation that these usecases would use a logical delete instead of true DELETE method?
If so, what would a recommended way to implement logical delete?

- two endpoints - one regular with a filter (active=true) and one special without one?
- modify DELETE method to switch to set the flag instead of truly deleting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest commit on v0.5dev [has `DELETE` included in the audit](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/commit/42f59bd6786e9862f90f9d17672990c3b008c674), document included, so your use case should be covered.

Comment: Awesome! :) I thought I was missing something and that was not a good way to go.

Comment: While we are on the topic, what's the rationale for deleting versions of a document when it is deleted? Doesn't this break the idea of data_relation with version=True? What would break if I simply stopped this history deletion on DELETE?

Comment: Yeah there's an [open ticket](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/issues/335) about that.